# How do I find hard drive details in Red Had Linux?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

Can anybody please tell me the command to find the hard disk details in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?
I have a bad hard disk on the server and I want to replace it with new one of same kind.

Answer (score 2):

`lshw` will help you! See the [dev site](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`hdparm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm).

> hdparm provides a command line interface to various kernel interfaces
>   supported by the Linux SATA/PATA/SAS "libata" subsystem and the older
>   IDE driver subsystem. Many newer (2008 and later) USB drive enclosures
>   now also support "SAT" (SCSI-ATA Command Translation) and therefore
>   may also work with hdparm. Eg. recent WD "Passport" models and recent
>   NexStar-3 enclosures. Some options may work correctly only with the
>   latest kernels.

Answer (score 0):

```
# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
```

will usually give you drive model numbers, i.e.

```
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: INTEL SSDSC2CT06 Rev: 300i
```

You could also use smartctl -i to print drive information:

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sda
...
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Intel 330 Series SSDs
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2CT060A3
...
```